# awk: Search missing value in file

Tags: awk

`awk` newbie here! I am asking for help to solve a simple specific task.

Here is `file.txt`

```
1
2
3
5
6
7
8
9
```

As you can see a single number (the number 4) is missing. I would like to print on the console the number 4 that is missing. My idea was to compare the current line number with the entry and whenever they don't match I would print the line number and exit. I tried

```
cat file.txt | awk '{ if ($NR != $1) {print $NR; exit 1} }'
```

But it prints only a newline.

I am trying to learn `awk` via this small exercice. I am therefore mainly interested in solutions using `awk`. I also welcome an explanation for why my code does not do what I would expect.

Comment: the variable is `NR`, remove the `$` prefix.

Comment: no keep it, if it confused you there will be others...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
awk '{ if (NR != $1) {print NR; exit 1} }' file.txt
4
```

Comment: @EdMorton - Roger That.

Answer (score 2):

since you have a solution already, here is another approach, comparing with previous values.

```
awk '$1!=p+1{print p+1} {p=$1}' file
```

you positional comparison won't work if you have more than one missing value.

Comment: perfect, just add may some explaination for OP who is learaning awk and you are using some shortcut. Also, need a loop if more than 1 number is missing between 2 line ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
seq $(tail -1 file)|diff - file|grep -Po '.*(?=d)'
4
```

Since I am learning `awk` as well

```
awk 'BEGIN{i=0}{i++;if(i!=$1){print i;i=$1}}' file
4

`awk` explanation read each number from `$1` into array `i` and increment that number list line by line with `i++`, if the number is not sequential, then print it.

cat file
1
2
3
5
6
7
8
9
11
12
13
15

 awk 'BEGIN{i=0}{i++;if(i!=$1){print i;i=$1}}' file
 4
 10
 14
```